# What is the book mentioning torches and lockpicking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The following answer and question references a book claiming that the heat of a torch somehow helps lockpicking:

- **[How do I succeed at lockpicking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36414/13090)**
- **[Does equipping a torch actually make picking a lock easier?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41788)**

Although it's been proven a [**false rumor**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41865/13090) nobody ever mentioned the name of the book or its location. What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book you are looking for is called: [Advances in Lock Picking](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Advances_in_Lock_Picking)

It exists in both Skyrim and Oblivion.  In Skyrim it can be found at:

- Bannermist Tower, on the second floor on a table on the other end of the room entrance. (North-West of Falkreath.)
- Chillwind Depths, on a table located in the last room of the cave.
- The Ragged Flagon - Cistern, on a barrel in the north east room.
- In the Riften Sewers behind a grate, on top of a barrel.
- On the body of a dead Redguard, west of Heartwood Mill.

Excerpt (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes the locks have weird spings. They all spring differently, which makes picking it hard. **I hold my torch close to the lock.** This makes it hot. When it's hot, the springs are all the same. They don't bounce so differently any more. Be careful not to burn yourself.